# how to boot a fedora arm raw image on Windows

Tags: fedora, qemu, arm

I want to run a fedora **arm** distributionon a windows 64bit machine.
Got stuck with qemu showing a dark screen, and whatever I have read and tweaked it seems not boot.

I did take the following installation steps

1. Fetched fedora server arm image: https://arm.fedoraproject.org/.
2. Installed latest qemu 64 for windows: https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/
3. Unpacked raw image  and extracted on a linux machine the kernel with the virt-builder --get-kernel Fedora-Server-armhfp-25-1.3-sda.raw, the kernel and the ramdisk (virt-builder is from libguestfs-tools)
4. Now i have 3 files transferred windows: kernel, ramdisk and the  Fedora-Server-armhfp-25-1.3-sda.raw

Now i tried to start the everything with the following command:

```
"c:\program files\qemu\qemu-system-arm.exe" -M raspi2 -m 512 -kernel ./vmlinuz-4.8.6-300.fc25.armv7hl -initrd ./initramfs-4.8.6-300.fc25.armv7hl.img  -redir tcp:2200::22  -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 vga=normal mem=512M devtmpfs.mount=0 rw" -drive file=Fedora-Server-armhfp-25-1.3-sda.raw,if=sd,cache=writeback
```

but whatever i try to change on the commandline, qemu only shows a black console screen and does not boot.

Comment: I'm not sure the server image is configured to use a graphical screen, I suspect it might only be accessible from a serial console. That's how I've been working with it.